# jQuery AJAX - Load specific node

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I am writing a quiz based AJAX called. So I'd like to load the questions in order. But I just don't know how.

My XML looks as follows :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <multichoice>
        <question>
            <body>
                <question_title>If you have to stop in an emergency on a wet road you should</question_title>
                <question_correct_answers>a</question_correct_answers>
                <question_answer_a>Keep both of your hands on the steering wheel</question_answer_a>
                <question_answer_b>Brake very gently</question_answer_b>
                <question_answer_c>Use the foot brake and handbrake together</question_answer_c>
                <question_answer_d>Always change down through the gears</question_answer_d>
                <question_explination>The best advice about emergencies is to avoid them. You can minimise the chances of an emergency by watching the road well ahead and anticipating the actions of other road users. In an emergency, react quickly and brake firmly while keeping both hands on the wheel. You must make sure that you keep full control of your vehicle all the time, to help you do this, concentrate on clear spaces, not the things that you are trying to avoid.</question_explination>
            </body>
        </question>
        <question>
            <body>
                <question_title>Which one of the following things is most likely to distract a driver</question_title>
                <question_correct_answers>a</question_correct_answers>
                <question_answer_a>Using the demisters</question_answer_a>
                <question_answer_b>Stopping at red traffic lights</question_answer_b>
                <question_answer_c>Operating the indicators</question_answer_c>
                <question_answer_d>Dipping the headlights</question_answer_d>
                <question_explination>Driver distraction is one of the biggest causes of accidents. There are lots of things that can cause you to become distracted these range from getting lost, to eating snacks or smoking cigarettes. Something as simple as operating the radio or the car&#x27;s air conditioning can distract you from the road ahead.</question_explination>
            </body>
        </question>
</multichoice>
```

When you first hit the page, I'd like to load that first question in. With its' title, answer_a, answer_b etc.

I do need to know the number of questions, So am looping through the question node.

But I'd like to load specifically the first question node and once a next action is complete, Load in the second node and so on.

My current jQuery is as follows :

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: question_path,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml)
            {
                var current_question = 0;
                var num_questions = 0;

                // Get Specific Question...

                // Get Number Of Questions...
                $(xml).find('question').each(function()
                {
                    num_questions++;
                })

                // Set Page Title
                $('.page__title').html('Question '+ current_question +' of '+ num_questions);
            }
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: You would want to store the XML and question count outside the ajax and access it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to store this data outside of ajax and access accordingly on press of next you would increment current question and use something like `$(question_xml).find('question').eq(current_question)`

```js
var current_question = 0;
var num_questions = 0;
var question_xml;
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: question_path,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml)
            {

                // add xml
                question_xml = xml;
          
                // Get Number Of Questions...
                $(xml).find('question').each(function()
                {
                    num_questions++;
                })

                // Set Page Title
                $('.page__title').html('Question '+ current_question +' of '+ num_questions);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Like it. How would I then in turn get the question_title ?

Comment: Try `$(question_xml).find('question').eq(current_question).find('body').find('question_title');` remember `current_question` is 0 based for it.